# Ist it possible to combine arbitrarily many timed Flux into one?

Tags: reactive-programming, project-reactor

I am aware about `combineLatest()` to combine the last values in two to six Flux instances ([Combining Publishers in Project](https://www.baeldung.com/reactor-combine-streams) ). However, assume I have a `List<Flux<Integer>> listOfFlux`. Is it somehow possible to combine all of them into one, like e.g. `listOfFlux.combineAllLatest( (a,b) -> a + b) )`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a operator variant just for that:

```
Flux.combineLatest(Iterable<? extends Publisher<? extends T>> sources,
                                          Function<Object[],V> combinator)
```

You can use it like:

```
List<Flux<Integer>> listOfFlux = //...
Flux<Integer> result = Flux.combineLatest(listOfFlux, arr -> {
    //...
});
```

Comment: Hmm, just tried it in my code. But also this example doesn't work, since the arr is of type Object[] it doesn't have a forEach method.

Comment: Yeah, I could produce working code with casting the Objects to other Types, this however isn't quite type safe. Do you think it makes sense to send a request for a type safe version to the guys from project-reactor?